# how to groupby dataframe with two rows as header

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe with two rows as header(name and unit). is there a way to groupby dataframe with unit. what Iam trying to acheive is group by similar units and run analysis on them.

df = pd.read_csv('filename',header=[0.1])

```
Customer  length   height  adress   city
Name        meter   meter   bldg    name

A         10        20      1       Delhi
C         30        20      10       Delhi
B         20        40      19       Delhi
D         40        50      10       Delhi
```

i am trying to isolate the dataframe with units(second header)
for example:

```
length   height
10       20
30       20
20       40
40       50
```

Comment: `df.groupby(level='Name', axis='columns')`

Comment: @PaulH i think i didn't explain it well. I mean to get the dataframe with units meter.

Comment: Can you please pos your expected dataframe, and what you tried..

Comment: that's what it's helpful to explicitly type out what your desired results are. perhaps `df.xs('meter', level='name', axis='columns', drop_level=False)` is what you want

Comment: But I think the groupby is actually what you want: `df.groupby(...).apply(<analysis_function>)`

Comment: @PaulH Thanks. it worked.

Comment: @PaulH please add as an asnwer

Comment: df.xs('meter',axis=1, level =1).plot()